# Custom CMS Block

Tags: template, cms, blocks

I want to display the output of a template on my homepage. It is meant to display the first level categories in my shop. What I have below isn't rendering. May I ask what I'm missing?

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/navigation/subcategory_listing.phtml" category_id="category/3"}}
```

PHTML File Below:

```
<?php
$_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories ();
$_helper = $this->helper ( 'catalog/output' );
?>

<div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing">

    <?php

    foreach ( $_categories as $_category ):
        ?>

        <?php if ( $_category->getIsActive () ): ?>
        <?php
        if ( $_category->getListingName () )
        {
            $name = $_category->getListingName ();
        }
        else
        {
            $name = $_category->getName ();
        }
        $_category = Mage :: getModel ( 'catalog/category' ) ->load ( $_category ->getId () );
        ?>

        <div class="listing-item">

            <?php if ( $_category->getImageUrl () ): ?>

                <div class="product-image col-md-4">

                    <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL () ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape ( $name ) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl () ?>" width="205" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape ( $name ) ?>"/></a>

                    <?php else: ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="product-cagetory-title"><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL () ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape ( $name ) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape ( $name ) ?></a></div>

                </div><!-- end col md 4 -->

        </div><!-- end listing item -->

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div><!-- end catalog listing -->
```

Comment: Can you poste some code of your .phtml

Comment: are you getting into the template at all?

Comment: Nothing renders if thats what you mean.

Comment: @MattMcLennan if you put a die on the first line do you get that far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to guess the problem is that there is no function `getCurrentChildCategories` on the block type `core/template`. What you could look into doing is making your own block with this function, the function itself can be found in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`

Or you could simply get the category you have set against the block and load the children from the category object.